# Changing user system passwords with a PHP script

Tags: php, linux, permissions

So I have a PHP script that needs to change a Linux user password programatically.

The script is running as `www-data` (which is the username given to apache2).  I execute `chpasswd` with `popen`, and then `fwrite` the username:password pair.  This causes an error.

Dropping down to a bash shell, I try to see what's going on here.  Naturally, I suspect it's some kind of permissions issue.  So, I change users to `www-data` and try to execute `chpasswd` manually:

```
# su www-data
$ /usr/sbin/chpasswd    
jsmith:mysecretpassword
Changing password for jsmith.
chpasswd: (user jsmith) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 1, user jsmith) password not changed
```

So this reveals why PHP is unable to execute the command.  The error message is not exactly straightforward, but I suppose the gist of it is that a [**PAM authentication**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) problem occurred (which I assume basically means a Linux permissions problem).  So, if I `su` to root, I'm successfully able to change the password via `chpasswd`.

So obviously the problem here is that apache2 (user `www-data`) doesn't have `sudo` privileges.  Is the only solution here to add `www-data` to the `sudo` group?  Because I'd rather not do that.  But I don't see any other option here.

More generally speaking - apart from the specifics of this situation - how is it even *theoretically* ***possible*** for a web program that might need to change user passwords to be able to do so without having `sudo` privileges?  But if the web program has `sudo` privileges, then isn't that a major security problem?

Comment: you mean you're checking their system login password? You can't change another user's password while running as a non-privileged user. You'll have to do this via `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I would likely setup a queuing system that runs as root and have the php script add to the queue instead of having PHP have access to any privilege escalation. This will also close some security holes although having web interface to changing linux user passwords still sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this](http://www.unicom.com/sw/web-chpass) and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-linux-or-unix-system-password-using-php-script.html). The second alternative, even though they have a "security" section at the bottom with suggestions, doesn't seem safe to me, but it's just a feeling.

I'd go for web-chpass.